# Capturar sequência de fotos e salvar automaticamente no Android

Tags: android, android-camera

Estou tentando usar a câmera do meu android em uma aplicação de forma que ao tirar a primeira foto eu não seja redirecionado para a tela inicial.

Atualmente o aplicativo está da seguinte forma:[image: Tela Inicial]

Ao clicar em "Tirar fotos calibragem" é direcionado para a câmera onde ao tirar a foto é perguntado se desejo guardar a foto ou repetir o processo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha pergunta é: Como capturar várias imagens de uma vez sem precisar voltar para a tela inicial e clicar em "Tirar fotos calibragem" novamente.

A seguir está o código da aplicação:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView; // campo onde sera exibido a foto
Button btnCameraCalibrate;
private File arquivo;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    btnCameraCalibrate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPicturesCalibration);


    btnCameraCalibrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            //cria pasta para guardar fotos
            File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM+"/Reccoon3D");
            if(!pictureDirectory.exists()){
                pictureDirectory.mkdirs();
            }
            //nomeia a foto baseada em data e hora
            String pictureName = getCalibrationPictureName();
            File imagemCalib = new File(pictureDirectory,pictureName);
            Uri pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(imagemCalib);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,pictureUri);


            startActivityForResult(intent,0);

        }
    });
}

private String getCalibrationPictureName() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    String timestamp = sdf.format(new Date());

    return "Calibration"+timestamp+".jpg";
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

   super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    //Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
    //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     }
}
```